# BroadcastReciever.onReceive startActivity doesn't display activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, start-activity

***None of the comments below worked for me.***

However, I have found a fix.  I needed to change my AlarmActivity and it seems the keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard was very important.

Code:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        this.setTurnScreenOn(true);
        this.setShowWhenLocked(true);
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
    }
}
```

***Initial problem was..***

I am trying to display an activity (startActivity) from a BroadcastReciever.onReceive method but it isn't working consistently.  The code I have seems to work well if the device is active but has issues when the device is locked.  The following code should be minSdkVersion 28 compliant.

The existing code uses an AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle to trigger a BroadcastReciever.  Depending on some values inside intent.getExtras the code should display either: AssessmentAlarmActivity or MATActivity.  AssessmentAlarmActivity needs to ALWAYS display even when the device is snoozing and on the locked screen.  MATActivity should display only if device is active (doesn't have to wake device or display on lock screen).

The following code seems to work on a lot of devices.  Looking at the logcat data, I see the BroadcaseReceiver.onReceive is getting triggered but sometimes the activity can take a minute before it will display.  On some devices the activity will never displays at all.  I am assuming the following code has incorrect values in the intent.addFlags code, but I am not sure.

AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle code:

```
private static void setAlarm(Context context, ResponseInfo responseInfo, int requestCode) {
    // Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ResponseAlarmReceiver.class);
    responseInfo.setRequestCode(requestCode);
    intent.putExtras(responseInfo.createBundle());

    // Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);

    am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, responseInfo.getAlarmTime(), pendingIntent);

    pendingIntents.put(requestCode, pendingIntent);
}
```

BroadcastReceiver.onRecieve code:

```
public class ResponseAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        // read the ResponseInfo from the extras
        ResponseInfo responseInfo = new ResponseInfo();
        responseInfo.readBundle(intent.getExtras());

        // log requestInfo data
        Log.i("ALARM", String.format("Now: %d, responseInfo: %s",
                System.currentTimeMillis(), responseInfo.toString()) );

        if (responseInfo.getAlarmType() == AlarmType.CANCEL) {
            cancelAlarm(context);
        }
        else {
            showAssessmentAlarm(context);
        }
    }

    private static void showAssessmentAlarm(Context context) {
        Log.i("ALARM", "showAssessmentAlarm top");

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(context, AssessmentAlarmActivity.class);
        nextIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(nextIntent);

        Log.i("ALARM", "showAssessmentAlarm bottom");
    }
    
    private void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        Log.i("ALARM", "cancelAlarm top");

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MATActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml definition of the activities:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MATActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

    <activity android:name=".AssessmentAlarmActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
```

MATActivity is a pretty standard activity, so I will skip that code.  AssessmentAlarmActivity does have a special settings and extends AlarmActivity:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // not minSdkVersion 28 complient, but this is what I have tested most
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}       
        
        
public class AssessmentAlarmActivity extends AlarmActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.assessment_alarm);      
        
        ..
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of background process limits.
try testing it again with phone plugged in (charging). if the issue solved so it's because of background process limits.

1. if you are making a alarm clock or a very important thing to do you can use [alarmManager.setAlarmClock()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). it will bypass the restriction.
2. don't forget to acquire a `wakeLock` immediately in `onReceive`. else android system may go to idle mode very soon.

note: you may just need the second part (acquiring a WakeLock). but implementing both is a stronger way.